# Animations not working on pseudo-elements? IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This is a problem for IE10 in particular. I'm animating a pseudo-element. When I hover the pseudo-element, `.skew` class is added to it, which triggers the CSS animation. When the animation is finished, `animationend` removes that `.skew` class.

At least that's what happens in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE10 the `.skew` class is added, but not removed when the animation is finished. I'm not exactly sure if that's the case, but it might be because hovering the pseudo-element the first time triggers the animation, but hovering it again doesn't (which would mean the `.skew` class wasn't removed at the end of the previous animation).

**See Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ldh5g/

```
$("div").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("skew");  
});

$("div").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("skew");
});
```

Anytime the pseudo-element is hovered, the animation plays. This is true for Chrome and Firefox. But in IE10 the animation can't play more than once. The thing is if I try this on a non-pseudo-element, it works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code with a toggle event. I haven't tried it but it should work even on IE10

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldh5g/4/

**JS**

```
$( "div" ).bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass("skew");
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I need the animation to be triggered upon hover, but finish playing itself even when unhovered. That's why ``animationend``.

Answer (score 0):

ie10 not yet support the animation events (bubbling) on the pseudo-elements.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for your notification.